# Probability that at least $2$ of a group of $4$ people were born on the same day of the week

Tags: probability

What is the probability that at least $2$ of a group of $4$ people were born on the same day of the week?

My attempt:

Probability that at least $2$ of a group of $4$ people were born on the same day of the week=1-probability that at most $1$ of a group of $4$ people were born on the same day of the week (NONE ARE BORN ON SAME DAY).

=$1-\frac{\text{Possibility none born on same day}}{\text{No. Of total possibilites}}$
=$1-\frac{4.5.6.7}{7.7.7.7}
=$0.659$

Comment: You need to state the assumption that the day of the week each person is born on is chosen uniformly at random and that the days were chosen *independently* for each person.  If I go to my friend's house who I know to be a twin and his twin happens to be there, I can be sure that at least two people have the same day of the week (*and in fact same birthdate*) that they were born on.  Or perhaps we live in a strange society where any baby born on a monday is sacrificed to the god of the moon, so you will never meet anyone born on a monday.

Comment: With those assumptions, your answer is correct.

Comment: Okay... Everything is randomly chosen

Comment: It should be ~0.650146.

Comment: Probability that no one is born on same day of the week makes sense similarly 2,3,4 people are born on the same day but exactly 1 person born on the same day does not make sense..... What about the mathematical expression for it ....?